# How do I save ionic array data in a .txt or .json file

Tags: json, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I have an array in ionic and I want to if I click a button called 'save' that a .txt or .json file should be created where the data in the array should then be saved. How can I achieve this with ionic? 
I'm very new to Ionic so I'd like to know how I can achieve this.

The array is as followed: `testnames = [{name : "sheldon", age : "10"}, {name : "Simon", age : "11"}]`.

Comment: Ionic native plugin [File](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file/) is a solution.

Comment: @HyuckKang that is indeed an option but I find the documentation in how to do it quite limited.

Comment: You mean that you seek more specific solution? What's your exact purpose with the file? Exporting it or storing it in app?